# Error handling postresql and nodejs query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I seem to be struggling to handle any database errors within my app. I have a simple query that updates a users password

```
// Update Users Password
async function updatePassword(password, id) {
  const client = await pool.connect();
  const sql = format('UPDATE users SET password = $1 WHERE id = $2');
  try {
    await pool.query(sql, [password, id]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred', e);
    client.release();
  }
}
```

Server side i have this in my routes.js

```
const newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.update_password, 10);
try {
  await queries.updatePassword(newPassword, req.body.user_id);
  res.status(200).send({ result: 'Password Updated Successfully' });
} catch (e) {
  res.status(400).send({ result: 'Oops, please try again' });
}
```

If there are no database errors then this works as expected, but if for example i supply a string as my id (forcing the error) then I get this error printed to the console as expected

```
Error Occurred { error: invalid input syntax for integer: "string"
```

but still `res.status(200).send({ result: 'Password Updated Successfully' });` is sent.

Logged as

```
POST /update_password 200
```

How can I capture the error as I thought I was being that its in the try/catch block ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is irrelevant of the libraries that you use. You simply misuse `async/await` error reporting.

Your function `updatePassword` does not re-throw the error, thus swallowing it. Have it re-throw the error, and the error will be reported correctly:

```
catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred', e);
    throw e;
  }
```

As for the database code, it also looks bad - you allocate a new connection inside the method, but release it only inside `catch`, which means the connection will remain occupied when no error thrown, thus quickly depleting the connection pool.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, have also refactored my database connections